# Fixed length of span size in input form

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I have a form with some input tags and for each of it(I'm using bootstrap). I would like to use span with backgroud coloro but I have a problem with the size of it, because depends of text length (the best way is to use awesome, but I don't find icons useful to my purpose).
Is there a way to fix the width of the grey part of div? I tried with width, like the image, but it resize all the input fields.Thanks
[image]

```
<div class="row">
<!-- Fleet fields -->
<div class="col-xs-6">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <i class="fa fa-car fa-fw"></i> Fleet inputs
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-heading -->
        <div class="panel-body">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Ap</span> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Application">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cubic">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">cm<sup>3</sup></span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <input type="number" class="form-control" placeholder="Power">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">H P</span>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Eu</span> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Euro class"> 
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Et</span> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Engine type">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Tr</span> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Traction">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">Ts</span> <input type="text"
                        class="form-control" placeholder="Transmission">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label>Note</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="2" maxlength="100"></textarea>
                </div>

            </form>
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel-body -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Css of input -group-addon
    .input-group-addon{color:#3c763d;background-color:#dff0d8;border-color:#3c763d}

Comment: Please add your HTML and CSS code.

Comment: I added html, I thought that was better to use an image

Answer (score 0):

you can use for fixed width of grey part of div

```html
you can use for fixed width of grey part of div

1.<div class="input-group input-group-lg">   <span class="input-group-addon" id="sizing-addon3">@</span>   <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" aria-describedby="sizing-addon3"> </div>

2. can use also another div <div class="input-group input-group-sm">
3. can use also <div class="input-group">


for the Icon you can use Class="fa fa-edit" or Class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"
```

for the Icon you can use Class="fa fa-edit" or Class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"